# jQeditRangeSlider values

Tags: jquery, uislider

I am using JQeditRangeSlider [jQRangeSlider project site](http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider)

I am trying to post values back to the server via ajax but don't know how to access the values (min and max).

I tried $("#elname").values(), .max() .... and it does not seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the "Usage" section of the [README on github](https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider/blob/master/Readme.md) it shows:

```
// Get the value
var max = $("#slider").rangeSlider("max");
```

It also lists these methods:

```
min(value): gets or sets the minimum value
max(value): gets or sets the maximum value
```

It also mentions a `valuesChanged` event that you can listen for and have a method run when the event occurs.

Comment: I just tried that and it only results in [div#elname.ui-rangeSlider ]

Comment: I don't wish to use the event and only need to capture the values on a ajax submit.  I tried var x = $("#slider").max(); but get max is not a function.  It renders correctly though.

Comment: I don't know how to include the external scripts for the control in jsfiddle

Comment: `$("#slider").max()` isn't what the README shows. It's `$("#slider").rangeSlider("max")`. If you need more help debugging, I suggest you create a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: To include the scripts in a jsfiddle you could put them on a server you have access to and link to them, or just copy and paste them them inline in `<script>` tags in the HTML.